# How to complete a process in Node JS after executing all the operations

Tags: node.js, kubernetes

I am very new to NodeJS and trying to develop an application which acts as a scheduler that tries to fetch data from ELK and sends the processed data to another ELK. I am able to achieve the expected behaviour but after completing all the processes, scheduler job does not exists and wait for another scheduler job to come up.

Note: This scheduler runs every 3 minutes.

job.js

```
const self = module.exports = {
  async schedule() {
    if (process.env.SCHEDULER == "MinuteFrequency") {
      var timenow = moment().seconds(0).milliseconds(0).valueOf();
      var endtime = timenow - 60000;
      var starttime = endtime - 60000 * 3;
      //sendData is an async method
      reports.sendData(starttime, endtime, "SCHEDULER");
    } 
  }
}
```

I tried various solutions such Promise.allSettled(....., Promise.resolve(true), etc, but not able to fix this.

As per my requirement, I want the scheduler to complete and process and exit so that I can save some resources as I am planning to deploy the application using Kubernetes cronjobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all your work is done, you can call `process.exit()` to cause your application to exit.

In this particular code, you may need to know when `reports.sendData()` is actually done before exiting.  We would have to know what that code is and/or see the code to know how to know when it is done.  Just because it's an `async` function doesn't mean it's written properly to return a promise that resolves when it's done.  If you want further help, show us the code for `sendData()` and any code that it calls too.

Comment: I have fixed the issue. Actually send data was async but it was returning as a callback for anonymous function, so i tried to return a Promise from the send data and then used await keyword, and then process.exit(). It worked. Thank you for guiding me.